# Location updates not working in service when app is minimized

Tags: android, android-service, locationlistener

I have implemented a LocationListener to receive regular updates in a service when app is minimized. However this does not work. Updates are only received when the app is visible. Location updates cease when screen is locked or app is minimized.

```
public class MapService1 extends Service {

private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 0;
private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES = 0;
protected LocationManager locationManager;

Location location;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES,
            MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES,
            new MyLocationListener());
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        System.out.println("----------------------NEW ON LOCATION CHANGED (" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude() + ")----------------------");
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @halfer noted...

Comment: What version(s) of Android are you experiencing the issue on? How is the service being started and stopped?

Comment: @clownba0t i'm currently running this on my oneplus3 with android 8. Service is started in my activity's onCreate but not stopped.

Comment: Are you targeting API 26 in your `build.gradle` file for the application (i.e. `targetSdkVersion 26`)?

Comment: @clownba0t my targetSdkVersion is 22

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Your problem is likely that your app only has permission to location while using the app. This will give you the option to accept location permissions all the time.